# Calling a method defined in another class

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

I am trying to build a GUI for an application using Tkinter and I'm not very comfortable with classes. Following is the code

```
class Search(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Search Algorithm")


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save settings", command=lambda:popupmsg('Not supported just yet!'))
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

        filemenu2 = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu2.add_command(label="Tutorial", command=lambda: popupmsg('In preparation!'))
        menubar.add_cascade(label="More",menu=filemenu2)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, Loginpage, Graphpage):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

    def show_frame(self, cont):


        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()



class Loginpage(tk.Frame,Search):


    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.label_user=tk.Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_user.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label_pass=tk.Label(self, text="Password")
        self.label_pass.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.entry_user=tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_user.focus_set()
        self.entry_user.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.entry_pass=tk.Entry(self,show="*")
        self.entry_pass.grid(row=1, column=1)


        self.button=ttk.Button(self, text="Login",command= self.Logincheck)
        self.button.grid(columnspan=2)

    def Logincheck(self):

        username = self.entry_user.get()
        password = self.entry_pass.get()

        # print(username, password)

        try:
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect(servername, username=username, password=password)
            self.button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Click to Continue",command= lambda: controller.show_frame(Graphpage))
            self.button1.grid(columnspan=2)

        except:
            tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect username/password")
```

What I'm trying to do is to open the Loginpage, take input for username and password and send command to the Logincheck function, if the username and password are right the program should display the Graphpage. But, I receive an error that controller is not defined. A part of the code has been taken from https://pythonprogramming.net/change-show-new-frame-tkinter/?completed=/passing-functions-parameters-tkinter-using-lambda/. The class-Loginpage inherits from the class-Search which contains the method show_frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you receive would be useful to see, but I think adding the following line to your __init__ function will solve your issue.

```
self.controller = controller
```

If this is not the solution, then update your question with the error you receive when running your code and i will update my answer.

edit: You will of course need to edit uses of controller in your class methods. Specifically for you, it seems only in the lambda expression in Logincheck function.

change this line:

```
self.button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Click to Continue",command= lambda: controller.show_frame(Graphpage))
```

to this:

```
self.button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Click to Continue",command= lambda: self.controller.show_frame(Graphpage))
```

Comment: Could you point me to a good reference for understanding classes?

Comment: There are lots of resources at hand with a google search. Maybe start here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM and then use that knowledge to ask google the right questions :)